# UnsatisfiedLinkError using JNI for Native C Package libfprint

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am trying to use a package in my final year project called [libfprint](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fprint/libfprint). This is an opensource fingerprint reader SDK. I am doing my project in Java so I need to port over the libfprint functionality.

A stroke of good luck hit me and turned out somebody already did this. A package called [jlibfprint](http://code.google.com/p/jlibfprint/) is a JNI wrapper for libfprint.

So I followed the instructions in both jlibfprint and libfprint for setup. libfprint more or less works fine. As for jlibfprint, when I tried to run the sample program I got,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no JlibFprint_jni in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1681)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:840)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1047)
    at JlibFprint.<clinit>(JlibFprint.java:28)
    at SampleRun.main(SampleRun.java:30)
```

> JlibFprint.(JlibFprint.java:28)

is referring to

```
 static {
    System.loadLibrary("JlibFprint_jni");
 }
```

So now I'm looking through the project properties and get to the field "Native library location", and I point it to the directory containing **a single file called libJlibFprint_jni.so**.

Now when I run the program, the error I get is,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: JlibFprint.enroll_finger()LJlibFprint$fp_print_data;
    at JlibFprint.enroll_finger(Native Method)
    at SampleRun.main(SampleRun.java:36)
Enroll the first finger...
```

Here are the sample Java file

SampleRun.java

```
public class SampleRun {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JlibFprint jlibfprint = new JlibFprint();
        JlibFprint.fp_print_data pd1, pd2;
        int matchValue;
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enroll the first finger...");
            pd1 = jlibfprint.enroll_finger();
            System.out.println("Compare the previous acquisition with the next one...");
            pd2 = jlibfprint.enroll_finger();
            matchValue = JlibFprint.img_compare_print_data(pd1, pd2);

            System.out.println(matchValue);
            if (matchValue > JlibFprint.BOZORTH_THRESHOLD)
            {
                System.out.println("[OK] The two fingerprints are compatible!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("[FAIL] The two fingerprints are not compatible!");
            }
        }
        catch (JlibFprint.EnrollException e)
        {
            System.err.format("Enroll Exception [%d]\n", e.enroll_exception);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with Eclipse Juno.

Anybody with a breeze of knowledge in this area would be a great help !

Comment: Even easier, you can define interfaces in Java corresponding to function signatures in libfprint and avoid the extra JNI library using JNA (http://github.com/twall/jna).

Comment: hmm, how quick / painless would this be to get started from scratch? I am a total JNI newb and have a barely functioning knowledge of C..

Comment: At the moment I have to use Linux because the only drivers for my reader are available on linux

Comment: You can map and use a native library in minutes.  As an exercise, pick any C library function, write a mapping for it, and run it.  See https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md or https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/DirectMapping.md for a simple C library example.

Comment: You can get UnsatisfiedLinks if your method signature doesn't perfectly match the exported JNI call. And as you know, the package name is part of the method signature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution [here](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2007/10/how-to-add-shared-libraries-to-linuxs.html). I'm sure it was obvious to some but JNI is totally new to me. The solution was:

> "Create a new file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ called .conf
>
> Edit the file and add a line per directory of shared libraries (*.so
>   files), it will look something like:
>
> /usr/lib/APPLICATION/lib Reload the list of system-wide library paths:
>   sudo ldconfig"

Comment: Define `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the path to the shared library.  `java.library.path` is based largely on that environment variable.  No restart nor system modifications required.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a bit late. But if you are using the eclipse for your java project then go to the `Run Configurations` and then go to the `Arguments` tab.

In the `VM arguments` add following line:

```
-Djava.library.path="${workspace_loc}/PROJECT_NAME/DIRECTORY_NAME_CONTAINIG_LIBRARY:${env_var:PATH}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna throw a few JNI related answers, feel free to downvote.

[Android Java JNI and C Char array Can't recognize the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137945/android-java-jni-and-c-char-array-cant-recognize-the-value/13722381#13722381)

The call needs to look like

```
JNIEXPORT <return type> JNICALL Java_<your_package_name>_<classname>_<methodname>(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, ...)
```

so lets try it out for an example that is

```
package com.rtrk.demo;
public class PELib 
{

     public native int play(String file, String file2, blahblah); 
 /* ... */ 
}
```

which should look like

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_rtrk_demo_PELib_play(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring main_video, jstring prev_video, jint main_x, jint main_y, jint main_width, jint main_height, jint prev_x, jint prev_y, jint prev_width, jint prev_height)
```

This is the main root cause for UnsatisfiedLinkErrors :)